Isotopy classes of homeomorphisms of $S_1$
I want to prove that the homeomorphisms of the circunference $S_1$ (as the complexes of modulo $1$) to itself are either isotopic to the identity or to complex conjugation. Any idea?
I suppose I could use the fact that the induced isomorphism of the integers $Z$ has to be the identity or the map $1$ to $-1$, since these are the only ones. And the last one corresponds to complex conjugation in $S_1$.
I have already proven that any homeomorphism of $S_1$ is isotopic to another one fixing the point $1$.
Thanks

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783635/every-continuous-map-fsn-to-sn-n-even-either-has-a-fixed-point-or-a-point/ perhaps this can help? It shows there's only two homotopy classes of maps and you know which ones the identity and complex conjugation fall in so it should complete it

But  there could be more of 2 isotopy classes (there must be only two, but it's not the same homotopy as isotopy).

Consider the map $e : [0,1] \to S^1, e(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$. It maps  $(0,1)$ homeomorphically onto $S = S^1 \setminus \{1\}$ and collapses the two-point set $\{0,1\}$ to the point $1 \in S^1$.
You already know that each homeomorphism of $S^1$ is isotopic to a  homeomorphism fixing $1$. So let $h : S^1 \to S^1$ be a homeomorphism with $h(1) = 1$. Define
$$H : (0,1) \xrightarrow{e} S  \xrightarrow{h} S  \xrightarrow{e^{-1}} (0,1) . $$
This is a homeomorphism. As a map $(0,1) \to (0,1)$ it must be either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.
Let us first consider the increasing case. In that case $H$ it extends to a homeomorphism $H' : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $H'(0) = 0, H'1(1) = 1$. We have $e \circ H = h \circ e$.
Define
$$\phi: [0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1], \phi(s,t) = (1-t)H'(s) +  ts .$$
This is a homotopy rel. $\{0,1\}$ from $H'$ to $id$. We claim that it is an isotopy. Clearly each $\phi_t = \phi(-,t)$ is surjective (apply to IVT to $\phi_t$). Since $H'$ is strictly increasing, for $s_1 > s_2$ we get
$$\phi_t(s_1) = (1-t)H'(s_1)+ ts_1 > (1-t)H'(s_2) + t s_2 = \phi_t(s_2) $$
which means that $\phi_t$ is strictly increasing, hence injective.
Thus $\phi_t$ is a continuous bijection between compact Hausdorff spaces, hence a homeomorphism.
$\phi$ induces a homotopy $\psi : S^1 \times [0,1]  \to S^1$ such that $e \circ \phi = \psi \circ (e \times id_I)$. It is a homotopy from $h$ to $id$.  By construction all $\psi_t$ are continuous bijections, hence homeomorphisms. Thus $\psi$ is an isotopy.
The decreasing case is similar. In that case $H$ it extends to a homeomorphism $H' : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $H'(0) = 1, H'(1) = 0$ which is isotopic to $\rho : [0,1] \to [0,1], \rho(s) = 1-s$.
This induces an isotopy from $h$ to the complex conjugation map.

Even better: This construction is so canonical that it gives a deformation retraction of the space $\mathrm{Homeo}^+(S^1)$ of orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of $S^1$ onto the subspace $S^1$ (the circle acting on itself via left translation).
